Is there a way to dynamically update your apps typography config in Angular Material 18?
I'm looking to drive font size as a configuration option in my applications settings, at the moment I have a single typography config set that is being applied app-wide.
@include mat.all-component-typographies($mat-typography);

It seems like updating the typography config would be the cleanest way of doing this, and I was hoping to find a way to update the config based on some mechanism I can control (like a class) but this doesn't seem like it's supported.
Is there a new method for doing this in Material 18? I have found some older blog posts that seemed like they are on the right track, but the mixins being used aren't available in this version of Material.
blog post I was reading - https://www.universal-tutorial.com/angular-tutorials/angular-typography

They guide you are looking at does not focus on Material 3 but on an older version of Angular Material. You might better have a look at the official Material docs.
This guide focusses on custom typography with Material 3 using Angular Material: https://material.angular.io/guide/typography
